# How to instantiate Ignite CacheManager with programmatic configuration / without XML

Tags: java, caching, ignite, jcache, programmatic-config

I want to create an Ignite node with a programmatic configuration. A `javax.cache.CacheManager` object is required for the application.

I know that I can start an Ignite node with the following code:

```java
//with XML configuration
Ignition.start("path-to-ignite-config-xml");

//with programmatic configuration
Ignition.start(cfg)

//with xml-config with the JCache-API   
Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(uriToXML, classloader);
```

The first two method calls got an Ignite object as a return value.
The last one got a `CacheManager` object as a return value.
But I would need something like this:

```
Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(IgniteConfiguration cfg);
// or this:
Ignition.start(IgniteConfiguration cfg).getCacheManager();
```

There's a method `org.apache.ignite.cache.CachingProvider.findManager(Ignite)` which has got the return type `javax.cache.CacheManager` (which is what I want)
but the return value is always `null`.

Is there a way to get a `javax.cache.CacheManager` object without XML config?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JCache API does not allow this and supports only URLs. You should use XML file for configuration, or use native Ignite API.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the issue in my code by ditching `CachingProvider` and writing my own implementation of the `javax.cache.CacheManager` interface.

I am creating an `Ignite` instance in the constructor of the `CacheManager` implementation and forwarding all the calls to it. `IgniteCache` is already implementing `javax.cache.Cache`, so no issues there.

It is not strictly JCache, but it is close enough for my purposes.